The minimum size of the picture buffer for inter prediction
I want to run the H.264 encoder on an FPGA, and I'm thinking whether it's worth trying to implement inter prediction if I have RAM limitations.
Do I understand correctly that the buffer size will be equal to the resolution multiplied bits on pixel, given that I am working with YUV 4:2:0 format? Or do I only need the Y brightness component?
Additionally, is there any way to use a compressed image that has already gone through entropy encoding (CAVLC or CABAC) for reference image buffer for inter-frame prediction? Otherwise, if I use the image after reconstruction(without CAVLC), its memory footprint is as large as the original, even though its quality is already reduced. This requires a significant amount of RAM, which is limited in FPGAs.
I have not found any examples in the open source that would not use RAM less than the full size of the uncompressed picture. For YUV at 720p, this is 1350 KB.


I'm thinking whether it's worth trying to implement inter prediction if I have RAM limitations.

I don't know much about FPGA, but I don't think you should worry about RAM. Less than 3MB might suffice.

Do I understand correctly that the buffer size will be equal to the resolution multiplied bits on pixel, given that I am working with YUV 4:2:0 fotmat? Or do I only need the Y brightness component?

I'm not sure to have understand this correctly. Using YUV 4:2:0 chroma sampling, the buffer has a size of :
width * height * 3 / 2


And is there any way to use an already compressed picture that has already passed through entropy encoding(cavlc or cabac) for inter-frame prediction? Otherwise, if you use the picture after the reconstruction conversion, it weighs the same as the original, although its quality is already lower. This fact requires a lot of RAM, which is not enough in FPGA.

As far as I know, it's not really possible.
It's called transcoding, but it's usually done by decoding and re-encoding.

I have not found any examples in the open source that would not use RAM less than the full size of the uncompressed picture. For YUV at 720p, this is 1350 KB.

This is correct ;
720 * 1280 * 3 / 2 = 1382400


I assumed it might be possible to write data after CVALC directly into the buffer of the reference image, and then, for inter-frame, retrieve it from this buffer using the decoder CVALC. This approach could potentially reduce the memory required for the reference image, as it would store the compressed image after CVALC. Otherwise, after reconstruction (without CVALC), the reference image largely contains unnecessary zeros, and its size remains the same as the original. Could you let me know if there’s a fundamental issue with this approach? Or is it simply uncommon practice?

I'm not sure to have you understand correctly ;

If your goal is to save the image being encoded CVALC or CABAC, it's completely feasible.

If your goal is to manage the encoding (CVALC or CABAC) for some operations, such as inter-frame prediction ; To my knowledge again, it might be possible, but hugely difficult and pointless, for 2 reasons :

Because computer works on bytes, and not on bits, it'd be hard to modify a single bit (shift everything on left or right)
Regarding CVALC more specifically. CVALC encodes in zig-zag. It's easy to work on a bitmap where each pixel is where it's supposed to be. Now imagine you have to work on this :




Source: Wikipedia
Encoding is usually made using Hardware Acceleration - which is now available on FPGA - to manage bitmaps efficiently, via a Transition Matrix. So it'd be nonsense to work directly on an encoded image.

If you encounter a genuine issue regarding memory. You may use an SD card (here's a similar question). Access time would be much slower, but it it'd solve your problem.

Thank you. I assumed it might be possible to write data after CVALC directly into the buffer of the reference image, and then, for inter-frame, retrieve it from this buffer using the decoder CVALC. This approach could potentially reduce the memory required for the reference image, as it would store the compressed image after CVALC. Otherwise, after reconstruction (without CVALC ), the reference image largely contains unnecessary zeros, and its size remains the same as the original.
Could you let me know if there’s a fundamental issue with this approach? Or is it simply uncommon practice?
